# How to implement an integration for start and end of a call in Vicidial

Tags: linux, asterisk

I've developed most of the application in PHP for the integration (very similar to our Asterisk implementation) and all we need at this point is to run `php async.php 12313123.12312` (shell command) (unique id as first param) at the start/end of every call (regardless of Inbound and Outbound) This will query vicidial_log for the correct information and use our API.

What I'm unsure on is the best place to put the code to execute the shell command. On our Asterisk implementation I added it to extensions.conf on the starting points of calls and h exten on calls. (Note: Inbound and Outbound) But obviously vicidial generates it's own extensions.conf so clearly that is not the best file to use.

Obviously I want this implementation to change as little as possible on Vicidial so if the client upgrades Vicidial it will be novel to setup the integration once more.

Also a side question due to my inexperience with Vicidial, does vicidial_log have pending calls (calls that have started but not ended)?

Comment: I recommend you first read book and read source of vicidial(yes, it is opensource product). Most effective way is modify vicidial functions.